# MS Graph API - Sharepoint Files query does not return all file types

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I'm using MS Graph API to search files stored into a specific folder on Sharepoint Online.

The URL is :

GET `/sites/{site-id}/drives/{drive-id}/root:/{folder-name}:/search(q='{file-name}')`

Basically, each query shall return 3 files : `foo.PDF`, `foo.DXF` and `foo.STEP` but currently only the PDF file is returned.

I am missing something or is there some limitation on "exotic" file extensions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have tested it with .pdf,.txt,.docx,.dxf and .step but got only results for .pdf,.docx.txt.

Comment: Hi bill, Please raise a uservoice for this in the [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) so that the product team can implement it in the future.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback, I'll do so.

Comment: Moving this to Answer

Answer (score 0):

Please raise a uservoice for this in the [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) so that the product team may implement this feature in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I found a list of file types that are currently crawled by Sharepoint Search :
[Default crawled file name extensions and parsed file types in SharePoint Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/default-crawled-file-name-extensions-and-parsed-file-types)

You can add custom file type but only for Sharepoint Server. So, there is no way to do that on the online version. See this article from Microsoft : [Add or remove a file type from the search index in SharePoint Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/add-or-remove-a-file-type-from-the-search-index)

But, I finally found a way to do what I want :

```
/sites/{$siteId}/drives/{$driveId}/root:/{$folder-name}:/children?\$filter=startswith(name,'{file-name}')
```

And it works fine!

Comment: Unfortunately I need a recursive search instead of listing children in 100 folders :(

Comment: Solution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/714877/graph-drive-search-returns-files-only-with-specifi.html